# how to make a variable in the main method accessible in other methods in C

Tags: c, scope

title pretty much says it all, simple example of what im trying to do:

```
int main()
 {
     int count = 1;
     someMethod();
     return 0;
 }

void someMethod()
 {
     count++;
 }
```

How can I get `someMethod` to change the value of count in `main`? is this possible?
I'm assuming its something has to be with the fact that count is in the scope of main but not in someMethod. I'm new to C programming so it seems like it should be something simple, but I'm not sure. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Pass it as an argument to the other function?

```
void func(int *arg)
{
    (*arg)++;
}

int main()
{
    int foo = 1;
    func(&foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you declare `count` as a global variable?

```
int count = 1;
int main()
{      
     someMethod();
     return 0;
}

void someMethod()
{
     count++;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because you don't need a global variable for this? Better avoid them.

Comment: wow im pretty dumb lol, i didnt realize i could do that, hurr durr!! thankyou!!!!

Comment: @H2CO3 why should I avoid global variables?

Comment: may be to avoid conflict between variable of your program and header files variable

Comment: completely forgot that we were talking about C:)